How can i make funds raised transferred to a wallet governed by voting?
For a ICO i search to know how programmatically transfer funds raised to a locked address where it is governed by vote.
No one can withdraw funds without the vote of community
I think DAOs do it but i search to do it with smart contracts
Best regards

To programmatically transfer funds raised in an ICO to a locked address governed by votes, you can use a smart contract with DAO-like functionality.
You basically need a Smart Contract that can be governed by community votes.
Assuming that you already know about the ICO smart contract ( and how it works) the details below are for you to be able to create a governance smart contract that can be used to store raised funds.
Mention Below are the steps you can follow to achieve this:

Visit to Openzeppelin's Github to find governance contracts
Go to [Openzeppelin's Doc][2] to understand how Governance contract work.
Once you get it, simply create a Dao smart contract that is capable of storing your funds and only release it when someone votes.

Pasting a sample code below of a super-simple Dao contract built using OZ contracts. its transparent upgradeable as well

Note: this sample code was generated using Openzeppelin Wizard

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/governance/GovernorUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/governance/extensions/GovernorSettingsUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/governance/extensions/GovernorCountingSimpleUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/governance/extensions/GovernorVotesUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/governance/extensions/GovernorVotesQuorumFractionUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/governance/extensions/GovernorTimelockControlUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract MyGovernor is Initializable, GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorSettingsUpgradeable, GovernorCountingSimpleUpgradeable, GovernorVotesUpgradeable, GovernorVotesQuorumFractionUpgradeable, GovernorTimelockControlUpgradeable {
    /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
    constructor() {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    function initialize(IVotes _token, TimelockControllerUpgradeable _timelock)
        initializer public
    {
        __Governor_init("MyGovernor");
        __GovernorSettings_init(7200 /* 1 day */, 50400 /* 1 week */, 10e18);
        __GovernorCountingSimple_init();
        __GovernorVotes_init(_token);
        __GovernorVotesQuorumFraction_init(4);
        __GovernorTimelockControl_init(_timelock);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function votingDelay()
        public
        view
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorSettingsUpgradeable)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingDelay();
    }

    function votingPeriod()
        public
        view
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorSettingsUpgradeable)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingPeriod();
    }

    function quorum(uint256 blockNumber)
        public
        view
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorVotesQuorumFractionUpgradeable)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.quorum(blockNumber);
    }

    function state(uint256 proposalId)
        public
        view
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorTimelockControlUpgradeable)
        returns (ProposalState)
    {
        return super.state(proposalId);
    }

    function proposalNeedsQueuing(uint256 proposalId)
        public
        view
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorTimelockControlUpgradeable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.proposalNeedsQueuing(proposalId);
    }

    function proposalThreshold()
        public
        view
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorSettingsUpgradeable)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.proposalThreshold();
    }

    function _queueOperations(uint256 proposalId, address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, bytes32 descriptionHash)
        internal
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorTimelockControlUpgradeable)
        returns (uint48)
    {
        return super._queueOperations(proposalId, targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _executeOperations(uint256 proposalId, address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, bytes32 descriptionHash)
        internal
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorTimelockControlUpgradeable)
    {
        super._executeOperations(proposalId, targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _cancel(address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, bytes32 descriptionHash)
        internal
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorTimelockControlUpgradeable)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super._cancel(targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _executor()
        internal
        view
        override(GovernorUpgradeable, GovernorTimelockControlUpgradeable)
        returns (address)
    {
        return super._executor();
    }
}

Hope this helps, thanks.

Thank you very much, i test it
